# How do brackets affect pandas.loc Dataframe Query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can not grab the following result:
Assuming I have a dataframe calles df_sc
and

```
bol1  = (df_sc['Language'] == 'EN')
bol2  = (df_sc['long_shortcut'] == myShortCut)

# XM1 is the name of a column
# the following two objects are different:

type(df_sc.loc[bol1 & bol2,['XML1']]) 
being:pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

type(df_sc.loc[bol1 & bol2,'XML1'])
being: pandas.core.series.Series
```

IN the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) there is no mention as to how is the query interpreted when referring to only one column, within or not within a list.

What is the logic behind?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's intended. You pass a list of columns, you get back a dataframe, you pass a column, you get a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is right there further down in the doc you linked:

> ```
> Single label. Note this returns the row as a Series.
>
> df.loc['viper']
>
> max_speed    4
> shield       5
> Name: viper, dtype: int64
>
> List of labels. Note using [[]] returns a DataFrame.
>
> df.loc[['viper', 'sidewinder']]
>
>             max_speed  shield
> viper               4       5
> sidewinder          7       8
> ```

It says *`List of labels. Note using [[]] returns a DataFrame`*. So, `['XML1']` is a list with single item. I think it is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks Andy, fair enough. ['XML1'] is a single value list.